# Run .vhd virtual machine on Windows 8 Pro

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, hyper-v

How do I run a .vhd file on Windows 8 Pro?

Which is better, VMware or Hyper-V? I prefer a free solution if it exists.

Comment: Hyper-V is a bare-metal hypervisor, it typically runs as operating system, not *inside* Windows. (Actually, it could run on Windows Server, but it still won't work with everyday use editions of Windows like Win 8 Pro).

Answer (score 2):

If by "run .vhd" you mean use it in Virtualized client then read the following.

Once you initialize the vhd file in your Disk Management and then disconnect it you can then provide the HD for your VMware Player Guest initial setup. As in the following image:

[image]

If you only need to access the files from the vhd you can easily mount the vhd file since that features is already built in Windows 8

Comment: I need to run the VM actually using VMware player. How did you get the Virtual Machine Settings window

Comment: @Saher select the VM and click *Edit virtual machine settings* in the right pane or start creating a new VM.